# Desktop Wallpaper not updating in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background

The wallpaper of my desktop is not updating.

The wallpaper updates on the lock-screen page as well as the small windows of workspaces seen when viewing all workspaces. However, the background of desktop does not change. 
The image of wallpaper in .cache folder has updated as well.

On running the follwing command

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "path_to_wallpaper"
```

The wallpaper of the desktop does not change. New wallpaper only appears on the lock-screen. The change is reflected on the desktop only on restarting. Is there a solution other than restarting my machine everytime I change my wallpaper?

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background
```

gives the following output.

```
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-opacity 100
org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#000000'
org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000'
org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'solid'
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom'
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///home/sandy/Pictures/Wallpapers/2016-03-29.jpg'
```

Following command output is given below

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.nautilus.desktop

org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-name 'Trash'
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop text-ellipsis-limit 3
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop background-fade true
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop home-icon-visible false
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible false
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop network-icon-visible false
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font ''
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop network-icon-name 'Network Servers'
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop home-icon-name ''
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible false
```

Comment: When do you expect it to update?

Comment: when I change the wallpaper from settings, the background image is not changing

Comment: Can you please include output of two commands, `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background` and  `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.nautilus.desktop`

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail? What exactly did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))